# Testing a Hotfix in Dynamics AX

Tags: axapta, dynamics-ax-2012, hotfix

Is there some way that I be able to know which functionalities are related to a hotfix installed in Dynamics AX? Normally the hotfix comes with a list of modified/added objects (which I can create unit tests to it) but not with a list of modified/added functionalities, which is what I need. How do you guys normally test a hotfix?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could look into the customer/partner source -

https://mbs.microsoft.com/customersource/UK/AX/
https://mbs.microsoft.com/partnersource/global/products/AX

As my company is gold partner we receive each month a list with hotfixes, that describe the functionalities changes, so maybe you could receive same list if you contact your regional Microsoft contact.

**UPDATE:**

From here:
https://msdnshared.blob.core.windows.net/media/2016/07/DynamicsAXLatestHotfixList20160701.xlsx
You can download a list with hotfixes and short description.
For KB3161035 - CDCR - Financial dimensions for Transfer Orders (TO)

The hotfix package that you provided has many more models that you actually need.
Look in the Hotfixinformation.xml there should be information which models you need for KB 3161035.
When searching in the file found that:
KB="3161035" - needs only model: AxModel ModelId="4568521"

So you could cut all other models files from folder /models/ and leave inside the folder only ModelId="4568521" and syp labels. Then install the hotfix.

That way you could test only the functionality you need 
CDCR - Financial dimensions for Transfer Orders

Best Regards,
Kristian

Comment: take for example this hotfix: https://mbs2.microsoft.com/Knowledgebase/KBDisplay.aspx?scid=kb;EN-US;3161035. it comes with a bunch of others via dependency. is there a place in this portal where it says all the functionalities that I need to test when installed it?

Comment: thank you for your reply. in this case, how I'm gonna know that I just need that model? for example: what if some dependency that comes with it is necessary? in the *.xml you pointed is there a way to know? one more thing: where did you get this kb list? is this the lastest version of it?

Comment: If there is a dependency, in the .xml file under models should be all the models. Anyway if there are a dependency that is not noted in the file, when installing the hotfix there will be an error and installation will be aborted.

Comment: do you have any idea then why microsoft add more models than are necessary in a kb executable?

Comment: I am not sure here. Last time when we asked the support to send us only hotfix for our problem they reply that there is a new policy and they have to sned the whole pack. Maybe this way it is easier for them to track the version of the application. Did you succeed installing and testing your hotfix?

Comment: unfortunately this kb is not complete, and we are still waiting for microsoft to release a new correction. anyhow, thanks for the help.

Answer (score 1):

Hotfixes are usually delivered as a module. To create a project with the elements affected:

1. Tools\Model management\Models installed - find the model by sorting in reverse number
2. Tools\Model management\Create project from model - lookup the same model

Hotfixes are testet by having a failing testcase before the install, then installing, then reapplying the test after install (hopefully succesful). In an ideal world you would have two identical systems (application and data), then apply the hotfix to one of them.

Run the impact analysis before installing [as explained here](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh335183.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396).

Comment: my current problem is *what* to test. normally a hotfix changes only one functionality, but sometimes it has impact in others. my question is about getting all of the functionalities impacted with the hotfix; more precisely, how to know it.

Comment: Answer updated, run impact analysis. A change in a central class or table could in principle (and in the real wold) affect all functionality. In that case test the high priority work flows.

Comment: i didn't understand that much about the impact analysis tool. i just executed it for two different kbs that had conflicts detected in the installer, but the impact analysis tool didn't returned anything.